# Highchart stacked area not functioning with missing datapoint

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The issue is that the percentage area function does not seem to work when a datetime series is missing a datapoint for some *t*.

E.g. removing

```
{
x: new Date("2008-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
y: 0,
drilldown: 'my_drilldown'
}
```

from the series in http://jsfiddle.net/qtoas0jg/3/, giving http://jsfiddle.net/qtoas0jg/4/.

The expected/desired behaviour is that the area should fill for all times *t*. After going through the documentation I conclude that `connectNulls:false`, also using `step:"left"` I can achieve the desire behaviour for one series, the one holding values for all *t*, but then again not for the second series.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I was not able to solve the issue using Highcharts functionality. Instead I (quite unrigiously) manipulated the series that I put in by adding value 0 for the missing *t*. If someone stumbles apon this issue, the following might be useful:

```
    let asd = []
    // Firstly finding which t:s that need to be added for respective series
    let to_be_added = series.map(arg_a => {
        return([arg_a.name,arg_a.data.reduce((acc_b,arg_b) => {
            // Adding all available t:s
            (asd.indexOf(arg_b.x.toString())>=0?0:asd.push(arg_b.x.toString()))
            acc_b.push(arg_b.x.toString())
            return acc_b
        },[])])
    }).map(arg_a => {
        return [arg_a[0],asd.filter(arg_b => arg_a[1].indexOf(arg_b)<0)]
    })
    // Adding the new timestamps with y:0
    to_be_added.map(arg_a => {
        series.map((arg_b,ind) => {
            if (arg_b.name == arg_a[0]) {
                arg_a[1].reverse().map(arg_c => {
                    series[ind].data.unshift({x:new Date(arg_c),y:0})
                })
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by Highcharts bug: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5634

To workaround use `timestamps` instead of `Date` object:

```
data: [{
    x: new Date("2008-10-31T00:00:00.000Z").getTime(),
    ...
}, ...]
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0wr3kvt1/